# Symfony PHPUnit mocking: Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_InvocationMocker::someMethod

Tags: symfony, testing, mocking, phpunit

My code:

```
public function testApiClient()
{
    $mock = createMockApiClient();
    dump($mock->someMethod());
}

protected function createMockApiClient()
{

    $mockApiClient = $this->createMock(ApiClient::class);
    return $mockApiClient
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('someMethod')
        ->will($this->returnValue('someString'))
    ;
}
```

So I have this error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method 
PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_InvocationMocker::someMethod()
```

I'm new in PHPUnit tests, so what to do? I can't understand why I do as wrote in example and no result - just error?

Answer (score 2):

So I started searching in google. Strange: no one answer. Searching on PHPUnit Github repository didn't get any solution or even tips how to solve problem.

After many different tries I **!found!** that method `will` return `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_InvocationMocker` class, and if I just write after `will` semicolon and then return `$mockApiClient` it returns `Mock_ApiClient_anyHash`!

So you have to finish build your mock and only then return it.